# What live sound editing\filtering libs are there for flash developers?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, audio, mxml

What live sound editing\filtering libs are there for flash developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SiON - Sound library for FlashPlayer?10, The PCM/FM/PSG sound module emulator, MML(Music Macro Language) compiler/sequencer and sound effectors are included:

http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/10/02/sion-released/

Sazameki - The Audio library to arrange or sounds the waveform which generated in Flash:

http://sazameki.org/

ASound - Easy audio library. (Planned to) Provide the API like DisplayObject?.

http://memo.kappa-lab.com/2009/04/post_38.html
(you may need to translate this...)

This are spark projects.

You can also find alot of good tricks and code at andre's michele page:

http://blog.andre-michelle.com/